# Unity 2D: My laser script is getting stuck on an if statement and I don't know why

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been making a laser in my 2D platformer for the past day. I've made the arm follow to cursor perfectly however on the script for the weapon it self doesn't work. Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

public float fireRate = 0;
public float Damage = 10;
public LayerMask whatToHit;

float timeToFire = 0;
Transform firePoint;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    firePoint = transform.FindChild ("FirePoint");
    if (firePoint == null) {
        Debug.LogError ("No firePoint");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (fireRate == 0) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    else {
        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire) {
            timeToFire = Time.time + 1/fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
}

void Shoot () {
    Debug.Log ("Works");
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
    Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePointPosition, mousePosition-firePointPosition, 100, whatToHit);
    Debug.DrawLine (firePointPosition, (mousePosition-firePointPosition)*100, Color.cyan);
    Debug.Log ("Works 2");
    if (hit.collider != null) {
        Debug.Log ("Work 3");
        Debug.DrawLine (firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        Debug.Log ("We hit " + hit.collider.name + " and did " + Damage + " damage.");
    }
}
}
```

The if statement in void Shoot isn't working. The first two debug messages in void Shoot show up in the log however the two in the if statement don't and I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: set a breakpoint on the line just below "hit.collider != null" and run the application....if it doesn't break, then your not reaching you code and the hit.collider is null.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not reaching my breakpoints. So why is hit.collider still null?

Comment: Have you put collider components on the objects you need to hit?

Comment: Yeah. I was aimin at the platform the player was standing on